# Unreachable rails application in simple docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I have a simple docker image with a bare-bones rails app defined in it.

When I run...

```
$ docker build myimage .
$ docker run -p 3000:3000 myimage
```

...and then run...

```
curl http://localhost:3000
```

...I get the expected response right back

However, when I run...

```
$ docker-compose up
```

...where my Dockerfile is the same as I used to create the image, the output indicates that the rails app is started and listening BUT when I run the same curl command I get no response, and the app shows no indication it has been reached. If I stop the container I get a "connection reset" from curl, which indicates it was somehow connected. (OR if I wait long enough with curl command hanging, I eventually get the same "connect reset" message.

EDIT: I noticed that the `docker-compose up` command's output does not include "Creating network...with the default driver"

Any ideas on how I might troubleshoot this?

Thanks

This is my docker-compose.yml...

```
version: '3'
  services:
    web:
      build: .
      ports:
        - "3000:3000"
```

Comment: Execute the command 'docker ps' ... In both cases your image must appear

Comment: I suggest you add the image name in your docker-compose as well (image: myimage) and that you perform a build as well: docker-compose up --build

Comment: Thank you. Tried those things. I do notice that there is no "Creating network...with the default driver" message. Could that indicate an issue?

Comment: Can you please add you `Dockerfile` ?

Comment: Same problem here. did you solve this?